# Stop text being sent to editor

Tags: autohotkey

Below script opens a browser to www.google.com

But the keys "ch" are sent to the editor window.

```
~c ::
~h::
If (GetKeyState("c","h") && GetKeyState("c","h")) {
    Run, "www.google.com"
    Return
}
Return
```

How can the script be amended so that no output text is sent to the editor ?

Alternatively can focus be removed from the current text editor (for example notepad) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of these two versions does what you need:

**Version 1**

```
c::
h::
If (GetKeyState("c") && GetKeyState("h")) {
    Run, "www.google.com"
}
Return
```

**Version 2**

```
~c::
~h::
If (GetKeyState("c") && GetKeyState("h")) {
    Run, "www.google.com"
}
Return
```

**Your mistakes:**

Take a look at documentation of [GetKeyState](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) command. First function parameter is name of the key you wish to check and second parameter is mode in which `GetKeyState` command should work. In your example `"h"` parameter is incorrect parameter.

Also you don't need two `returns`.

Here `~c ::` space will give you error. It should be like `~c::`

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

**Edit:**
If the hotkey has prefix `~` then when the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked (hidden from the system). So, if we write `~c::` ,  when you press <kbd>c</kbd> then it will act as a hotkey in your script and also `c` will be send to active window. If we write `c::` , when you press <kbd>c</kbd> then it will act as a hotkey in your script but nothing will be send to active window. Also look [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm) in the table for more details.

Comment: thanks, if I can ask for more detail : what is the purpose of ~c:: , is there documentation on this function ?

Comment: @blue-sky You are welcome. I edited my answer and explained there purpose of `~` (look at text under **Edit:**).